# What is the required velocity that a rocket should have to escape earth's gravity?

Tags: orbit

This is for my end project. Thank you.

Comment: A simple google search would give you the answer. Or try "Escape velocity" on Wikipedia.

Comment: Your question is a little to simple for this site - I think you can look up escape velocity anywhere; Google, Wikipedia, etc.. Another thing you could do is just search this site for "earth escape velocity" or some permutations. Since the answer is likely here already, your question is likely to be closed as a duplicate. However if you have a more in-depth question that is not answered here already, definitely ask! :-)

Comment: In the mean time, just read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) or you might find [GSU's hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vesc.html) site more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum velocity required from Earth is

```
v=sqrt(2gR)
```

which you could've easily looked up on the Web.